# Parse 2 lists and create a comparison table

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am working on a screen which provides comparison between 2 `lists` basically.

I have a class `RateFactorItem`, which contains a `Name` property and a List of `ProductValues`.

```
public class RateFactorItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<ProductValues> ProductValues { get; set; }
    }
```

The `ProductValues` class is defined as:

```
public class ProductValues
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public double? Value { get; set; }
    }
```

I have another class called as `CompareViewModel`, which I use to populate the compare screen.

```
public class CompareViewModel
    {
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
        public double? VersionA { get; set; }
        public double? VersionB { get; set; }
        public double? Variance { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have 2 lists of `RateFactorItem` populated using few methods, sample code is written below.

```
public static List<RateFactorItem> GetRecordsA()
        {
            var items = new List<RateFactorItem>
            {
                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "Item1",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                {
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=200},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=300},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=400},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=500},
                    new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 1000 },
                }
                },

                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "Item2",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                {
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=250},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=350},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=450},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=550},
                    new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 1050 },
                }
                },

                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "Item3",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                {
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=2300},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=3030},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=4040},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=5030},
                    new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 1400 },
                }
                },

                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "ItemX",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                {
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=20},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=30},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=40},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=50 },
                    new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 60 },
                }
                }
            };

            return items;
        }

        public static List<RateFactorItem> GetRecordsB()
        {
            var items = new List<RateFactorItem>
            {
                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "Item1",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                {
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=230},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=340},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=470},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=590},
                    new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 1010 },
                }
                },

                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "Item2",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                {
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=220},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=370},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=400},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=510},
                    new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 150 },
                }
                },

                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "Item3",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                {
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=2900},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=3930},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=4940},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=5930},
                    new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 1900 },
                }
                },

                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "ItemY",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                {
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=40},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=80},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=90},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=60 },
                    new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 70 },
                }
                }
            };

            return items;
        }
```

In the controller action method, I try to create a list of `CompareViewModel` and populate the UI as below:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new List<CompareViewModel>();

            var productNameA = "product1";
            var productNameB = "product1";

            var recordsA = Records.GetRecordsA();
            var recordsB = Records.GetRecordsB();

            var countA = recordsA.Count();
            var countB = recordsB.Count();

            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(countA, countB); i++)
            {
                var itemName = countA > countB ? recordsA[i].Name : recordsB[i].Name;
                var recordA = recordsA.Where(x => x.Name == itemName)?.FirstOrDefault();
                var recordB = recordsB.Where(x => x.Name == itemName)?.FirstOrDefault();

                var subModel = new CompareViewModel
                {
                    ColumnName = itemName,
                    VersionA = recordA != null ? (recordA.ProductValues.Where(x => x.ProductName == productNameA).FirstOrDefault()?.Value ?? 0) : 0,
                    VersionB = recordB != null ? (recordB.ProductValues.Where(x => x.ProductName == productNameB).FirstOrDefault()?.Value ?? 0) : 0,
                    Variance = ((recordA != null ? (recordA.ProductValues.Where(x => x.ProductName == productNameA).FirstOrDefault()?.Value ?? 0) : 0) - (recordB != null ? (recordB.ProductValues.Where(x => x.ProductName == productNameB).FirstOrDefault()?.Value ?? 0) : 0))
                };
                model.Add(subModel);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

For demo purposes, I have the number of items in `recordsA` and `recordsB` same, but in real time, the number of items can differ.

In the above example, the compare screen is populated as below:

[image: Image 1]

The common items Item1, Item2, Item3 are shown, while only 1 uncommon item in shown in the screen.
I want that all the common and uncommon records should be shown in the grid, and obviously uncommon records would have a zero for their opposite counterpart, something like below:

[image: Image2]

So if list1 has 28 records, list 2 has 32 records, out of which 10 are common, then the resultant comparison screen should show the 10 common records and the uncommon records from both the lists.

I tried using `Intersect`, `Except` and `Concat` operators but wasn't able to achieve the desired result.
Note that `RateFactorItem` doesn't have an Id field, because these are never stored in the DB, all calculated on the fly and shown on the screen.

Please assist with pointers.

Comment: Easy.  Do it all the time.  It is similar to an excel Pivot Table.  Will work on solution

Comment: @jdweng - okay, please do.

Answer (score 0):

I built a DataTable with the results

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<RateFactorItem> recordA = GetRecordsA();
            List<RateFactorItem> recordB = GetRecordsB();

            var results = (from a in recordA
                           join b in recordB on a.Name equals b.Name
                           select new { a = a, b = b, name = a.Name}
                           )
                           .Select(x => (from ap in x.a.ProductValues
                                         join bp in x.b.ProductValues on ap.ProductName equals bp.ProductName into abp
                                         from bp in abp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                         select new { ap = ap, bp = bp, name = x.name }
                                         ).ToList()
                           ).ToList();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Item", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("product", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("A Quantity", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("B Quantity", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Variance", typeof(int));

            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                foreach (var product in item)
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        product.name,
                        product.ap.ProductName,
                        product.ap.Value,
                        product.bp.Value,
                        (product.bp.Value == null) ? (int)product.ap.Value : Math.Abs((int)product.ap.Value - (int)product.bp.Value)
                    });

                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
        public static List<RateFactorItem> GetRecordsA()
        {
            var items = new List<RateFactorItem>
            {
                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "Item1",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                {
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=200},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=300},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=400},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=500},
                    new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 1000 },
                }
                },

                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "Item2",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                {
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=250},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=350},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=450},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=550},
                    new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 1050 },
                }
                },

                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "Item3",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                {
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=2300},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=3030},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=4040},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=5030},
                    new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 1400 },
                }
                },

                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "ItemX",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                {
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=20},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=30},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=40},
                    new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=50 },
                    new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 60 },
                }
                }
            };

            return items;
        }

        public static List<RateFactorItem> GetRecordsB()
        {
            var items = new List<RateFactorItem>
            {
                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "Item1",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                    {
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=230},
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=340},
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=470},
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=590},
                        new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 1010 },
                    }
                },

                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "Item2",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                    {
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=220},
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=370},
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=400},
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=510},
                        new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 150 },
                    }
                },

                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "Item3",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                    {
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=2900},
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=3930},
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=4940},
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=5930},
                        new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 1900 },
                    }
                    },

                new RateFactorItem
                {
                    Name = "ItemY",
                    ProductValues = new List<ProductValues>
                    {
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product1", Value=40},
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product2", Value=80},
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product3", Value=90},
                        new ProductValues{ ProductName="product4", Value=60 },
                        new ProductValues { ProductName = "product5", Value = 70 },
                    }
                 }
            };

            return items;
        }
    }
    public class RateFactorItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<ProductValues> ProductValues { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProductValues
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public double? Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a column for both Items and Products.  You solution was missing a column.